# How to open the popup modal in ajax response (using magento jquery widget) in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, jquery, widget

I need to change my Java script code to jquery widget.Please provvide me a solution

**js file**

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui",
    "Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal",
    "slickslider",
    'mage/url'
],
        function ($) {
            "use strict";


            var popup = {
                type: 'slide',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: false,
                buttons: false,

                modalClass: "bottom-side-popup",
                clickableOverlay: true

            };

            var popupmodel = $('#wrapper').modal(popup);
            $(".products-btn").click(function () {

                popupmodel.modal("openModal");


            });

            $('.list-product').slick({
                slidesToShow: 8,
                slidesToScroll: 1

            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use '**define**' instead of '**require**' if want to use in JS file:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      /** This is demo for how you can use it in .phtml files**/
      require(
          [
              'jquery',
              'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
          ],
          function($,modal) {
              var options = {
                  type: 'slide', // or popup
                  responsive: true,
                  innerScroll: true,
                  modalClass: 'add-modal-class'
              };
              var popup = modal(options, $('#id-of-content-div'));
              $("#btn-clickable").on("click",function(){
                  $('#id-of-content-div').modal('openModal');
              });



          }
      );
  </script>
```